Using map() with GAM model
I have a code that works if I am using LM but not if I am using a GAM. I guess the that for whatever reason LM looks inside object for the variable and GAM just looks at the names of the object but I do not have a clue.
library(modelr)
library(purrr)
library(mgcv)


dataf <- data(cars)

dataf <- mtcars

df_split <- crossv_mc(dataf,10)

# LM - works
fn_model <- function(df){
  lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df)
}

df_split_model <-
  df_split %>%
  mutate(model = map(train, fn_model)) %>%
  print()

# GAM - does not

fn_model <- function(df){
  mgcv::gam(mpg ~ wt, data = df)
}

df_split_model <-
  df_split %>%
  mutate(model = map(train, fn_model)) %>%
  print()


#But i can do
gam(mpg~wt,data=mtcars)


You need to explicitly convert the resample object you are passing to fn_model to a data frame. It seems that gam is a little more particular than lm about the objects you can pass to the data argument.
fn_model <- function(df){
  mgcv::gam(mpg ~ wt, data = as.data.frame(df))
}

df_split_model <-
  df_split %>%
  mutate(model = map(train, fn_model)) %>%
  print()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    train                test                .id   model 
#>    <list>               <list>              <chr> <list>
#>  1 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 01    <gam> 
#>  2 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 02    <gam> 
#>  3 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 03    <gam> 
#>  4 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 04    <gam> 
#>  5 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 05    <gam> 
#>  6 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 06    <gam> 
#>  7 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 07    <gam> 
#>  8 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 08    <gam> 
#>  9 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 09    <gam> 
#> 10 <resample [25 x 11]> <resample [7 x 11]> 10    <gam> 

